# Why does Django in docker container not work?

Tags: django, docker

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.6.5-jessie
MAINTAINER example-user

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y vim
RUN mkdir require
COPY ./requirements.txt require/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r require/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
```

**requirements.txt**:

```
Django==2.0.2
```

As above, I made a image that has name `sample-image`

Next, I runned a container from `sample-image` like,

`docker run -ti --name sample_django -p 8001:8000 sample-image /bin/bash`

And on container bash, I commanded like,

```
root@4a947abf5ce5:/# mkdir startdir && cd startdir
root@4a947abf5ce5:/startdir# django-admin startproject sample .
root@4a947abf5ce5:/startdir# python manage.py runserver
```

it returned it:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 14 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

May 01, 2018 - 12:44:45
Django version 2.0.2, using settings 'sample.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Because I set -p 8001:8000 on running container, I found this page in browser( 127.0.0.1:8080), but it did returned it:

[image]

**QUESTION:**
How can I set port on container correctly? Or is there anything i missed?

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks Alasdair, If you reply as answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the docker container, use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` so that `runserver` doesn't just bind to `127.0.0.1`.